# Какие проблемы можно решить с помощью замыканий в С++?

Tags: c++

Какие проблемы замыкания решают более элегантно, чем до появления возможности их использования в С++? Просмотрев множество статей, пока что не нашел особых преимуществ их использования.
Будут полезны примеры использования  замыканий и их преимущества перед остальными решениями проблемы.

привел надуманный пример с использованием замыкания, однако видно, что задачу можно решить обычной функцией с двумя параметрами.

```
void scaling_point(vector<double> &point, double scalar) {
  for_each(point.begin(), point.end(), [scalar](auto &a) {a *= scalar;});
}

int main() {

  auto generate_scaling_funct = [](auto scalar) {
    return [=](vector<double> &point) {
      for_each(point.begin(), point.end(), [scalar](auto &a) {a *= scalar;});
    };
  };

  auto scaling2 = generate_scaling_funct(2);
  auto scaling3 = generate_scaling_funct(3);

  vector<double> point1{ 1,1,1 };
  scaling2(point1);

  vector<double> point2{ 1,1,1 };
  scaling3(point2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: В принципе можно вполне обойтись без них. Даже когда нужна передача каких-то "лишних" параметров - это можно сделать через глобальные переменные, например, или написание своего класса-функтора. Так что дело вкуса - писать ли видимую везде функцию или класс строчек на 10-15 там, где можно обойтись 20-30 символами... Понятно, что это - снижение зависимостей и сокращение и повышение понятности кода - особым преимуществом считаться не может :) А главное - все равно все, что написано с ними или без них - превращается в машинные команды, так что встает вопрос о преимуществах самого С++...

Comment: Использование локальных переменных вызывающей функции. Только синтаксис отвратительный, у меня вызывает резкое отвращение. Расширение GNU nested functions значительно лучше (но в крестах не работает -))

Comment: там, где алгоритм требует функтор, можете применить лямбду, но не обычную функцию.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А можно пример? Просто мне кажется, что можно (конечно, отвратительно эстетически :)) выкрутиться с помощью глобальных переменных.

Comment: @Harry, согласен, выкрутиться почти всегда можно, но я говорил(т.е. ТС сам гоаорил об этом) о передаче самой функции